# What does an exclamation mark before a cell reference mean?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a text about Excel I have read the following:

```
=SUM(!B1:!K1)
```

when defining a name for a cell and this was entered into the `Refers To` field.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When entered as the reference of a `Named range`, it refers to range on the sheet the named range is used on.

For example, create a named range `MyName` refering to `=SUM(!B1:!K1)`

Place a formula on `Sheet1` `=MyName`. This will sum `Sheet1!B1:K1`

Now place the same formula (`=MyName`) on `Sheet2`.  That formula will sum `Sheet2!B1:K1`

Note: (as pnuts commented) this and the regular `SheetName!B1:K1` format are *relative*, so reference different cells as the `=MyName` formula is entered into different cells.

Answer (score 1):

If you use that forumla in the name manager you are creating a dynamic range which uses "this sheet" in place of a specific sheet.

As Jerry says, Sheet1!A1 refers to cell A1 on Sheet1. If you create a named range and omit the Sheet1 part you will reference cell A1 on the currently active sheet. (omitting the sheet reference and using it in a cell formula will error).

edit: my bad, I was using $A$1 which will lock it to the A1 cell as above, thanks pnuts :p

Comment: if you try to put `=!A1` into a cell formula you get a message popup telling you there is an error in your forumla. You can't use this in a cell.