# On a spreadsheet what does A:A and !A:A mean?

Tags: spreadsheet

I have come across this sumif formula, I cant find any help doing a Google search on the `N:N`

```
=sumif(N:N,"Cat",C:C)
```

So I understand the SumIf, as per the docs:

```
SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range])
```

But I don't fully understand the `N:N`. Also please explain `!A:A`

Can someone provide an official explanation or point me to the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`N:N` means that the range includes the whole column N, rather than just certain cells (e.g. N1:N300). This allows a formula to reference all data in the column even if you add more rows later on.

The exclamation mark is explained here: [What does an exclamation mark before a cell reference mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27037152/2831209)

> When entered as the reference of a `Named range`, it refers to range on the sheet the named range is used on.
>
> For example, create a named range `MyName` refering to `=SUM(!B1:!K1)`
>
> Place a formula on `Sheet1` `=MyName`. This will sum `Sheet1!B1:K1`
>
> Now place the same formula (`=MyName`) on `Sheet2`.  That formula will sum `Sheet2!B1:K1`
>
> Note: (as pnuts commented) this and the regular `SheetName!B1:K1` format are *relative*, so reference different cells as the `=MyName` formula is entered into different cells.

Answer (score 0):

A clear answer to `N:N` was given. For the rest..
The exclamation mark in `!A:A` just means that you refer to another spreadsheet in your workbook -> say you currently work in Sheet2 and want to get Data from Sheet1. for this you have to use Sheet1 `!A:A`