# Repeat Titles but Recalculate Formula in every page in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created a worksheet with 40 pages. I know it's impossible to Repeat Bottom Cells when printing, so I just repeated the `Top Rows` (which contains a `Sum` formula) to make the sheet more compact. But the problem is, the sum formula in the top row computes only data from the first page. Ist possible to compute the data in every page when printing, somehow like what we could do in `Microsoft Access' header`?

Comment: The [Sum function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89) can sum values within multiple sheets. You can use the exclamation point followed by the name of the sheet followed by the range address to lock the given range from the given sheet. Like `Sheet1!A1`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037152/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-before-a-cell-reference-mean) question also contains some more interesting details on the use of the exclamation point. Do you want to change the formula when printing? Is a VBA solution fine for you?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey I don't need to lock the range, I just need to change the range on the fly. e.g. The header uses =Sum(A1-A10) on Page 1 and uses =Sum(A11-A20) on Page 2. I can easily do this on MS Access but not on excel. VBA is fine for me. I hope you could point me to some helpful links. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub SubSpecialPrinting()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim IntCounter01 As Integer
    Dim IntPagesToBePrinted As Integer
    Dim LngRow As Long
    Dim RngRangeWithFormula As Range
    Dim RngSumRange As Range
    Dim StrExistingFormula As String
    Dim WksWorksheet01 As Worksheet
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set RngRangeWithFormula = Range("I1")
    Set RngSumRange = Range("A1:A10")
    Set WksWorksheet01 = RngSumRange.Parent
    StrExistingFormula = RngRangeWithFormula.Formula
    IntPagesToBePrinted = ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")
    
    'Disabling interruption in case of error.
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Covering all the pages to be printed.
    For IntCounter01 = 1 To IntPagesToBePrinted
        
        'Setting the formula in RngRangeWithFormula.
        RngRangeWithFormula.Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RngSumRange)
        
        'Printing the single given page.
        WksWorksheet01.PrintOut From:=IntCounter01, _
                                To:=IntCounter01, _
                                Copies:=1, _
                                Collate:=True, _
                                IgnorePrintAreas:=False
        
        'Setting LngRow equal rows of the page just printed.
        LngRow = WksWorksheet01.HPageBreaks(IntCounter01).Location.Row - 1 - LngRow
        
        'Setting RngSumRange for the next page to be printed.
        Set RngSumRange = RngSumRange.Offset(LngRow, 0)
        
    Next
    
    'Reactivating interruption in case of error.
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Reporting the pre-existing formula in RngRangeWithFormula.
    RngRangeWithFormula.Formula = StrExistingFormula
    
End Sub
```

Change RngRangeWithFormula and RngSumRange value accordingly to your needs. The subroutine will print the pages of the print area one by one. Before printing, it will change the value of the RngRangeWithFormula with the sum of the values in RngSumRange; the latter will change for each pages, shifting down for as many rows as the given page contains. At the end of the subroutine, the RngRangeWithFormula will have the same formula it had before the subroutine was run.

Since one should call the subroutine in order to print the sheet correctly, i've spent some hours looking for a way to obtain the same result via a function. I've found how to know to which page a given cell belongs, but I haven't found a way to dynamically use the page number while printing. In the end i've accepted the subroutine as the way to go. Still in order to avoid the pointless printing of the "uncorrect" sheet and to make it easier for the user, i've written this extra code to be put in the workbook module:

```
Public PubBlnDedicatedPrinting As Boolean
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    
    'Checking if a dedicated printing is in process.
    If PubBlnDedicatedPrinting = False Then
        
        'Checking a specific sheet is active.
        If ActiveSheet.Name = "INSERT YOUR SHEET NAME HERE" Then
            
            'Asking if the user want to use the dedicated macro for printing.
            Select Case MsgBox("Do you want to run the dedicated macro for printing?", vbYesNoCancel, "Dedicated macro")
                Case Is = 6
                    'Setting PubBlnDedicatedPrinting value is set to true.
                    PubBlnDedicatedPrinting = True
                    'Running the dedicated macro.
                    Call SubSpecialPrinting
                    'Setting PubBlnDedicatedPrinting value is set to false.
                    PubBlnDedicatedPrinting = False
                    'Canceling any other printing procedure.
                    Cancel = True
                Case Is = 7
                    'Proceeding with a classical printing.
                    Cancel = False
                Case Is = 2
                    'Canceling any printing procedure.
                    Cancel = True
            End Select
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

To make it effective, you need to sobstitute the "INSERT YOUR SHEET NAME HERE" with the name of your sheet. Once the user will try to print the given sheet, Excel will ask him whether he wants to run the dedicated macro or to print it the classical way or neither or those.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I've changed RngRangeWithFormula and RngSumRange, changed "INSERT YOUR SHEET NAME HERE" and save my workbook as 'Macro-enabled' "*.xlsm".

Comment: 1) No error though? 2) What values did you assign to each variable? 3) Did you run the subroutine SubSpecialPrinting manually? 4) Do you get any error running it after turning on the interruption in case of error (there is one line of code to deactivate to achieve that)? 5) Was the sheet you want to print activated? 6) Is nothing printed or is it printed with the wrong value in the RngRangeWithFormula?

Comment: 1) No error. 2) RngRangeWith Formula = Range("A15"), RngSumRange = Range("A20:A30"). 3) Does not work when printing normally (Alt + F11), but when I run the module, it works, but (A) does not respect Page Break, (B) prints each page as "Separate Sheets/Documents" as opposed to printing "Single Sheet with Multiple Pages", (C) Cancelling print does not work, I have to wait until it finished spooling all the pages as separate sheets (and with 37 pages, it does take long).

Comment: 4) I don't seem to understand this. (5) Yes, the sheet was activated. The sum does not show on Print Preview but it was printed when I run the module (VBA). (6) All pages were printed, 1st page got correct Sum but subsequent pages did not. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) Ok. 2) They seem fine. 3) Ok, we might check later why the normal printing doesn't work; (A) i think i'll need an extract of your data, even with fake values; i just need a model of what you have and of what the result should be; probably the first 3 pages of column A will be enouth; (B & C) ye, i've looked for a way to make it a single printing document, but haven't found anything useful; anyway you might be interested in [this video](https://youtu.be/SMdV7Pz6kg0?t=279) since it gives you a way to obtain the print-preview the old way (so any printing-related macro will run to create [...]

Comment: [...] the print preview). 4) Nevermind, we will eventually return to this later. 5) Ye, check the video i've linked you before for an alternative print-preview. 6) Right now my hypotesis is that your data are a continuous list of numbers that continues from A31 and therefor you want the formula not to jump to the other pages but to keep on the list; i'll need your data to see if it's my assumption is valid.